# EXCEL VBA TYPE MISMATCH (13) TIME STAMP DIFFERENCE

Tags: excel, vba

[Excelfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZCK7.jpg)
 Hello I have an excel files with time stamps in a row as shown in the image 
I want to calculate the difference and enter the value in a new column. I tried the following code but it shows a type mismatch error and I don't know why. 
I know its easy, but I'm new to VBA so please help me.

```
\\Sub macro1() 
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim k As Integer
  i = 1
  j = 2
  k = 2
  Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
  Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value
  i = i + 1
  j = i + 1
  k = i
  Loop
  End Sub
```

Comment: Are `Cells(k, 2).Value`, `Cells(j, 1).Value`, and `Cells(i, 1).Value` all numbers?

Comment: no they are of the format 02/10/2018 08:08:20
02/10/10 09:09:20 i have uploaded the image
i,j,k are integers

Comment: Are those strings or actual date/time numbers? Also I'm confused by how you want your loop to work; the first iteration `k = j` but every other iteration, `i=k`

Answer (score 1):

Your format (2.10.2017 08:08:30) should be manipulated before using CDate to convert the cell value into a date, then use the VBA function DateDiff. See below. Put =timeDiff(A2,A1) in B2, then copy to B3 and down. Below is the VBA code.

```
Public Function transformCellStrInDate(ByVal rng As Range) As Date
Dim splitArr As Variant, dateArr As Variant, dateStr As String

splitArr = Split(Trim(rng.Value))
dateArr = Split(splitArr(0), ".")
dateStr = dateArr(0) & "/" & dateArr(1) & "/" & dateArr(2) & " " & splitArr(1)
transformCellStrInDate = CDate(dateStr)
Erase dateArr: Erase splitArr

End Function

Public Function timeDiff(ByVal rngY As Range, ByVal rngX As Range) As Long

timeDiff = DateDiff("n", transformCellStrInDate(rngX), transformCellStrInDate(rngY)) / 60 ' in Hours

End Function
```